# Wrapper Ktrain for Text Classification Multiclass - Parallelize the fit with CPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, text-classification, ktrain

I'm trying to solve a multiclass classification problem with BERT by leveraging the Ktrain wrapper. Having a large amount of data, I wanted to know if it is possible to parallelize the learner.fit_onecycle (3e-4, 5) function or the autofit () function.

For example as happens with sklerarn where you specify the number of parallel jobs, with the n_jobs parameter.

You can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use DistilBert instead of BERT in **ktrain**, it will cut your training time in half.  Second, multiple cores should be used by default by TensorFlow2 when calling any of the *fit* methods in **ktrain** using a CPU.  You can [control the number of CPU cores](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34415), if you want.